# Height 100% on justified inline-block div's

Tags: html, css, height, justify

I have a page with a dynamic number of boxes that I would like to distribute over several columns and lines.

I have the following wishes:

- Content of the boxes is different in height, but I want all div's in one 'line' to have the same height for visual appearance. They have a border and background color.
- I'dd like to justify columns over the page width

Ideally I'dd like the page to be responsive, so the number of columns should adjust to the browser width. But after reading and watching a lot of examples I don't see how this is possible in combination with the justifying, as that always needs a row div.

So I'm going for a fixed number of columns. With all kinds of examples I came to this solution, but there is still one challenge: getting each div to have the same height:

http://jsfiddle.net/johannesklapwijk/BQJ6A/

HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>a<br/>b</div>
    <div class='cell'>a<br/>b<br/>c</div>
    <div class='cell'>a<br/>b</div>
    <span class='stretch'/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
}
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    width:30%;
    height: 100%; /* does not get the height of the parent div */
    border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: green;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

I have two questions I guess:

1. The first question (might make the other absolete), is there a better solution, for example with jQuery to really make a dynamic grid of div's that distrubute nicely based on browser width?
2. If not: can the height problem be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So like this? (Change the con width to 100% if you want it the size of the browser)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="col">asd</div>
    <div class="col">asdasdasd
        <br />asdas
        <br />asdasd
        <br />asdasd
        <br />asdasd</div>
    <div class="col">asd</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.con {
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SM8x3/)

And for if you want it the size of the browser change `width` on `.con`

```
width: 100%;
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SM8x3/1/)

and if you want the spacing like you have on yours add `border-spacing` to `.con`

```
border-spacing: 10px;
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SM8x3/2/)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't justify the columns. 

I would like to have spacing between the boxes, but in your example that could be arranged with a child div in the table cell div although it would be nice to prevent it.

I've also been thinking of adding a text-align left to column 1 and and text-align right to column 3, but I was hoping I could do it without that so I might get to a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: @JohannesKlapwijk In last DEMO the boxes have space between them. And what do you mean by "justify the columns"

Comment: I do not see spacing between the cells? I'dd like to have room between the cells and by justifying I mean that the last cell will have no spacing on the right and the first will have no spacing on the left. Wich will usually occur if you add margins to your cell. (See my jsfiddle, I hope that clarifies)

Comment: @JohannesKlapwijk Check it on this one. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SM8x3/4/)

Comment: That's close, except that the left column has spacing to the left and the right column to the right...

Comment: @JohannesKlapwijk are you going to have a fixed amount of columns? If so this will be easier to fix.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no chaoice.. I was hoping for something responsive and flexible, but I doubt it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find something that meets my needs and I'm afraid CSS only is not enough.

I guess the jQuery freewall plug-in might give me what I need, even though it might be a bit heavy for my wishes.

http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/